# Get video data from Dailymotion

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Recently i'm working with the dailymotion video API. However I not sure how to convert the returned data into my ASP.NET C# application.

GET

```
https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?search=fun&page=3
```

RESULT

```
{ "page": 1,
  "limit": 2,
  "total": 218248,
  "has_more": true,
  "list": [
      { "id": "xrk9mi",
        "title": "Priyanka & Shahid Kapoor get MOBBED in local train",
        "channel": "fun",
        "owner": "xlw7uu"
      },
     { "id": "xrk8fy",
        "title": "What's Up With Gaga?: Hit On Head, Perfume Bottle Leaked, Thai Fans Angry",
        "channel": "music",
        "owner": "xofeoz" }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would declare a class that matches up with what you're getting back, let's break it down into parts, starting with the outer class declaration:

```
public class DailyMotionVideo {
  public int page {get;set;}
  public int limit {get;set;}
  public int total {get;set;}
  public bool has_more {get;set;}
  public XXX[] list {get;set;}
}
```

So I'll do the same with XXX which needs to be a separate type so we can make an array of them:

```
public class DailyMotionVideoInternalList {
  public string id {get;set;}
  public string title {get;set;}
  public string channel {get;set;}
  public string owner {get;set;}
}
```

Which requires us to go back and put that name into our first declaration:

```
public class DailyMotionVideo {
  public int page {get;set;}
  public int limit {get;set;}
  public int total {get;set;}
  public bool has_more {get;set;}
  public DailyMotionVideoInternalList[] list {get;set;}
}

public class DailyMotionVideoInternalList {
  public string id {get;set;}
  public string title {get;set;}
  public string channel {get;set;}
  public string owner {get;set;}
}
```

And then you can convert the received object into this object via many methods, depending on which .NET version you're using.

Since you've already got it as a string, I'm going to assume the string is called "result":

```
DailyMotionVideo videoList = 
           new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DailyMotionVideo>(result);
```

Comment: Another question, how to bind the videoList into a repeater?

Comment: Which, DailyMotionVideo (which is not a list) or DailyMotionVideoList? Regardless, assuming the repeater is named `rpt`, it would be `rpt.DataSource = videoList; rpt.DataBind();`